# PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value by the 3rd level but with indices

Tags: php, arrays

I'm totally desperate.
How can I sort an array in 3rd level that has an ID in the second level?
I want to sort this array only for "cars" and then ascending by "age"

```
array (   
    ['cars'] => array (
        [23] => array(
            ['age'] => 10,
            ['color'] => 'yellow',
        ),
        [16] => array(
            ['age'] => 12,
            ['color'] => 'purple'
        ),
        [45] => array(
            ['age'] => 3,
            ['color'] => 'silver'
        )
    ),
    ['pages'] => array (
        [0] => array (
            ['number'] => 2
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Try PHPs built-in function `uasort()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`uasort`**](https://www.php.net/uasort).

```
uasort($a['cars'], function($a, $b) {
   return $a['age'] > $b['age'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

https://eval.in/200162

Comment: @Tipo That's it. Have a look at the eval link

Comment: actually no need for a ternary on the return, `$a['age'] - $b['age']` is okay on integers

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the array values and don't care for the keys, use sort(). This will give a   new array with numeric keys starting from 0.

If you want to keep the key-value associations, `use uasort().`

check this [comparison table of sorting functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).